# Is install4j jdk 8 compatible?

Tags: install4j

I'd like to know if install4j is jdk 8 compatible or tested against or will be :)

Just found 1.7 Version to be tested on there site.

And if not what is the roadmap for next release supporting that?
Thx
Inge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install4j installers work with Java 8. The install4j currently (as of 5.1.6) requires Java 6 or Java 7.

Comment: So there is no way yet to build the installer with install4j (5.1.11) running with java 8?

Comment: The generated installers run with Java 8, it's just the install4j IDE and the compiler that require Java 6 or 7.

Comment: Is a new release planned to support java 8 for compilation? We want to switch our build system to java 8 and therefore we will need this feature.

Comment: To specify our problem more detailed we are using a dependency compiled with java 8 for our custom component. So we get a `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` error during project compilation.

Comment: For that purpose you can set the JDK on General Settings->Java version->JDK for code editor.

Answer (score 0):

From their blog [Migrating to install4j 6](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2014/11/migrating-to-install4j-6.html):

> **The minimum Java version for the install4j IDE and the compiler is now Java 7.** If your build machine only has Java 6 installed, you have to install a Java 7 JRE. On Windows and Mac OS X, Java 7 JREs are bundled in the install4j downloads.

**Therefore, I suppose install4j IDE version 6 supports also Java 8**, because they did not specify maximal Java version.