# auto-updating JavaFX/ScalaFX client installation

Tags: javafx-8, scalafx

Is there any ready-made installer, component, api or any combination, that would let a JavaFX application, or any JVM based client for that matter, automatically and securely check for a new version of itself, and get, install and re-launch the new version?

Although not ideal, is it doable at least with `sbt`?

Answer (score 2):

in the Moment there is only a feature request for Java 9

Take a Look at this aproach which seems straight forward

[AutoUpdate by Reportmill](http://reportmill.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/automatically-update-your-javapackager-applications/)

Answer (score 2):

[Install4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) is a a tool for creating installers for JVM applications, it provides for creation of auto-updates

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html

You can also build Install4J projects from SBT using the [sbt-install4j](https://github.com/jpsacha/sbt-install4j) plugin (disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin).

Comment: some time ago i asked about install4j and java 8 compatibility and it seems not to support all but maybe in the meantime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788578/is-install4j-jdk-8-compatible/19809136#19809136

Comment: I use Install4J with Java 8 for a while, did not noticed any issues. Looking at release notes for [5.1.13 2014-08-22](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html), it added Java 8 support for installer compilation.

For Scala/ScalaFX/SBT projects I use [sbt-install4j plugin](https://github.com/jpsacha/sbt-install4j). It builds installers with Java 8 with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to believe that the most practical (partial) solution is Java Web Start. Mature, documented, and comes along with the JRE and JDK. I wonder if anyone had experience with it for ScalaFX or JavaFX applications.